# Percent similarity of two ranges of numbers

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the percent similarity or overlap of two ranges of numbers.

For example, consider the ranges [10,1] and [5,1]. the range [5,1] covers 50% of the range [10,1], and a range [100,50] covers 0% of [10,1].

Edit: forgot to state the question. How do I do this?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @EJoshuaS "I am trying to get the percent similarity or overlap of two ranges of numbers." that s it

Comment: That's a *statement*, not a question. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just get the `Count` of the `Intersection` and compare it to the `Count` of the range we're interested in, for example:

```
var firstRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var secondRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);

var secondPercentCoverageOfFirst = 
    (double)firstRange.Intersect(secondRange).Count() / firstRange.Count() * 100;

Console.WriteLine($"{secondPercentCoverageOfFirst:0.00}%");

Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

---

Of course this would apply to **any** set of comparable objects, not just ranges of consecutive numbers...

```
var firstSet = new List<string> { "car", "bus", "boat", "plane" };
var secondSet = new List<string> { "bicycle", "car", "boat", "motorcycle" };

var secondPercentCoverageOfFirst = 
    (double)firstSet.Intersect(secondSet).Count() / firstSet.Count() * 100;
```

**Output for both cases**

[image]